# How to make LC tank circuits oscillate continuously?

Tags: capacitance, inductance

An LC tank circuit produces oscillations, when the capacitor is charged and connected to the inductor, but the oscillations decay gradually. How to make it continue, i.e. oscillate continuously?

I know we need to add energy continuously, but I don't know *how*.

Could anyone describe a circuit that provides a non-decaying oscillation?

Comment: Would [electronics.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: Google "LC oscillator".

Comment: I googled but they all explaining about "How LC circuit produce oscillation", what I need is how to make oscillations continuously without decay, and how exactly it works?.

Electricity is not a better home.

Comment: Make the L of the LC resonator the secondary winding of a transformer and couple energy into the LC resonator by driving the primary winding of the transformer at the resonant frequency. If the Q factor of the LC is large, only a small driving signal will be needed.

Comment: You add a negative resistor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2faJ4NI.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Here is an LC Oscillator that is easy to understand. 
All the values are examples only.

However, it is necessary to select the four equal resistors fulfilling the condition  R2/R1=R4/R3.

In theory, you could drop the resistor R3 - however, in this case you should know the damping properties (that means the parallel loss resistance Rloss) of the tank circuit.

Because this is not possible it is wise to heavily damp the LC circuit with R3 because,in this case, the losses of the componenets L and C are "overshadowed" and play no role.

Thus, you have an opamp with two feedback pathes (positive and negative) which cancel each other for one single frequency only: The resonant frequency of the tank which gives the oscillation frequency.

**Remark**: For a safe start of oscillations it is necessary to slightly increase the non-inverting gain (1+R2/R1) above its nomional value. That means: R2/R1>R4/R3.

Comment: It is difficult for me to realize this point
"LC tank oscillates when dc applied and removed, but when continues dc applied(like in transistor based oscillators) L should act as short circuit making capacitor to remain in discharged state, then where comes energy loss+oscillation".


correct me as soon as possible if I seem to be in wrong path of vision...


if you want explain with this ckt try the link(ckt is fm transmitter): 
http://www.buildcircuit.com/simple-steps-for-making-fm-transmitter/

Comment: Yes - I am afraid, you are "on the wrong path". You shouldn`t make things too complicated (non-realistic). There is no IDEAL tank which could oscillate continuously. Regarding the DC voltage source: It has (theoretically) zero source resistance - and, thus, acts as a short for any oscillating signal. My recommendation: Concentrate on real and working oscillator circuits only. Do you understand the working principle of the shown opamp circuit?

Comment: yes I know how the above circuit works through feedback. why current oscillates in tank circuit even it has path to flow forward along the circuit.

what I am trying to say:
when cap is charged and connected to inductor current has to exite the inductor because it has no other path and after inductor stores energy it also charges capacitor by loosing its energy(all this happens when only inductor and cap are considered ). 
what if cap and inductor are connected to constant dc? will currenr oscillates within tank or will it acts as LC in parallel.may be I am asking too much

Answer (score 3):

> Could anyone describe a circuit that provides a non-decaying
>   oscillation?

Honestly, this should be asked at the EE stack exchange site since, for one thing, there is a built-in schematic editor.

Essentially, one can drive the LC tank circuit at or near resonance frequency with a feedback amplifier.

A simplified example of a [Hartley oscillator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hartley_oscillator) is

[image]

The tap on the inductor allows the the battery to periodically, through the FET, add energy to the tank circuit.

Note that this is *not* a practical circuit as drawn but it should serve to get the essential idea across.

As the tank oscillates, the FET is driven on and then off.  You can find [here](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/e-hartley.html) an interactive simulation of a simple Hartley oscillator.

Answer (score 0):

The best example I can give you is a traditional tattoo machine, theoretically. Energizing a set of coils results in turning itself off when coil attracts the "armature bar" in turn opening the circuit where the A-bar is connected to a tension spring against a contact point. When coil deenergizes the A-bar is returned back to the contact point to turn itself on again and that process repeats itself continuously directly proportional to dc voltage applied by power supply.